# Spring Data Mongodb - Override mapped property in child class

Tags: spring, mongodb, polymorphism, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have polymorphic collection in MongoDB, parent abstract class and the few children classes that describe different types stored in this polymorphic collection. I want to have one field in all children classes but by different type for each child class:

```
public class MyParent {
    private SomeType filed; // embedded object
    ...
}

public class MyChild1 extends MyParent {
    @DBRef
    private SomeType filed;
    ...
}
```

I get MappingException about field duplication in these classes:

> Ambiguous field mapping detected!

- I'm working on existing DB. No any DB changes are possible.

How can I handle such DB structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Would `class Model<Detail> { @DbRef private Detail detail; } @Document class Child extends Model<ChildDetail> {}` work? I have [a sample on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/38813498/src/main/java/org/example/domain) that uses this approach and works fine at least when unit testing. I have used [Fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) for quick testing, although a real MongoDB server could be used easily by changing the configuration.

Comment: @manish Is Product.detail is DBRef in your example?

Comment: @manish I think you example is OK. But I need that Product.detail will be embedded document, for example,  and Category.detail will be DBRef...

Comment: Can't you create two different classes with the same field name, one with `@DbRef` and another with simply `@Document`? So, instead of `class Model<Detail> { ... }`, you would have `class Model1<Detail> { private Detail detail; }` and `class Model2<Detail> { @DbRef private Detail detail; }`. You can then extend from whichever one is suitable for your specific scenario.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. But I have many Model classes and lot of them have Detail as DBRef. So it's easy to have DBref in parrent class and just override it in some of children.

Comment: Let us say your design has 100 classes, all of which need to have a `detail` property. Let us also assume that 80 of these need to have this property as a `@DbRef` and the other 20 as `@EmbeddedDocument`. What I am suggesting is that you could have two base classes - one with a `@DbRef private Detail detail` property that 80 classes would extend and a second with an `@EmbeddedDocument private Detail detail` property that the other 20 classes would extend. Surely, this is more manageable than all 100 extending from the same base class and 20 classes overriding the property declaration.

Comment: @manish I didn't understand you answer correctly. Yes, this is looks good. Actually, both parent classes may extend the one top parent class and contain only one property ... Thanks.